# django filer dumpdata missing images

Tags: django, django-filer

I'm having an issue trying to migrate content from my local development django cms with sqlite3 backend to AWS, with postgres. I'm using the following command to dump all the page data, titles, plugins and presumably, the filer images

```
manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 --natural-foreign --exclude cms.pageuser cms filer aldryn_bootstrap3 djangocms_column cmsplugin_filer_image cmsplugin_filer_file djangocms_googlemap djangocms_link djangocms_style djangocms_text_ckeditor > all_content.json
```

However, when i try to run loaddata in my staging environment, I get an foreignkey integrity error - specifically around the table filer_file. Looking at the table structure, for every image I have in filer_image, I should have a foreignkey reference in filer_file- which doesn't reflect what is in the JSON dumpfile.

Strangely, for documents(eg pdfs) the dumpdata command works fine, it is just related to images. Furthermore, if I manually generate the missing json data it works just fine.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I've just upgraded to the following versions and still seeing the error.

```
aldryn-bootstrap3==1.0.10
cmsplugin-filer==1.1.2
colorama==0.3.3
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.9.7
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
django-classy-tags==0.7.2
django-cms==3.3.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
django-durationfield==0.5.2
django-extensions==1.6.7
django-filer==1.2.4
django-fixture-magic==0.0.8
django-formtools==1.0
django-mail-templated==2.6.2
django-mptt==0.8.4
django-polymorphic==0.8.1
django-reversion==1.10.0
django-sekizai==0.9.0
Django-Select2==4.3.2
django-storages==1.4.1
django-treebeard==4.0.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.3
djangocms-attributes-field==0.1.0
djangocms-column==1.6.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.4.0
djangocms-inherit==0.2.1
djangocms-installer==0.8.8
djangocms-link==1.7.2
djangocms-style==1.7.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.9.3
docutils==0.12
easy-thumbnails==2.3
html5lib==0.9999999
jmespath==0.9.0
Pillow==3.3.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
pyasn1==0.1.9
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.4
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.0.1
six==1.10.0
sqlparse==0.1.19
tzlocal==1.2.2
Unidecode==0.4.19
```

Comment: It pays to have the same database locally as you have in production. Then this would have been just a matter of pg_dump and restore. If you are having trouble with FK, dumpdata the offending tables individually and load them one by one

Comment: @e4c5 thanks, I probably am going to go down this route regardless but I wouldn't have thought this would matter in this particular case. For further context, I have 50 files total comprising 40 jpegs and 10 pdfs - this is represented correctly in the filer table: filer_file. Filer_image also shows the 40 images correctly. doing a dumpdata filer.file results in only the pdf entries being output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround, not quite the answer. I believe the issue lies somewhere in the polymorphic/filer grey area. Writing your own serializer to mimic what dumpdata does, solved my issue.

Logged a bug request regardless.

https://github.com/divio/django-filer/issues/887

Comment: I think I need this... How does one implement and run the referenced script?